# .db file from Heroku app does not sync with github repository

Tags: github, heroku, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this app on Heroku that deploys code from a GitHub repository. In this GitHub repository, there is this database file "something.db", which has all the necessary fields but empty of any records. When I build the app on Heroku and deploy it, it pulls the code from the GitHub repository, including the "something.db" database file. When people access the website, when they register a user account for example, the app inserts a new record to the database "something.db". However, I have some a concern about this:

How would I be able to sync this "something.db" database file from the Heroku app back to the GitHub repository? I.e. How can the GitHub repository be able to see the data changes in the "something.db" database file once I create a new user on the website.

I am asking this question in the context that every time I need to push code onto that GitHub repository, I would need to redeploy the app from heroku, which will then also deploy the empty "something.db" database file, which I do not want, since I want to retain the data that was previously added while the website was live.

I know this method of storing data in a .db file is not professional, but I would like to keep things as simple as possible since this website is small scale and does not hold that much data.

The app that I am using is a python Flask app, and the database is using flask alchemy (sqlite).

I tried looking online for some answers on how to push the changes from Heroku back to the GitHub pipeline but could not find anything about it. All I saw was how to deploy an app FROM GitHub to Heroku, but not push code FROM Heroku back to the GitHub repository.

Comment: I think you will run into a host of problems trying to store your data this way and using GitHub as the source of record for it. If you are not going to use a fully featured database or a cloud database like Fauna, then you could try storing this file in S3 or some other cloud file system.

Comment: Since I am familiar with MongoDB, it shouldn't be a problem to connect to the cloud database from there right?